# How do I serve MathJax from a local Happstack server?

Tags: haskell, mathjax, happstack

I'm not a developer/programmer. I'm just someone trying to use [Gitit](https://github.com/jgm/gitit) to take notes. I've got it to the point where it runs on Windows, but the math looks best using MathJax. I don't want to rely on a remote CDN to get the MathJax working (power cuts and internet disconnections are very frequent here). The author of the app mentions it can be setup in "4 lines of code" in Happstack:

```
mathjax-script: https://d3eoax9i5htok0.cloudfront.net/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
# specifies the path to MathJax rendering script.
# You might want to use your own MathJax script to render formulas without
# Internet connection or if you want to use some special LaTeX packages.
# Note: path specified there cannot be an absolute path to a script on your hdd, 
# instead you should run your (local if you wish) HTTP server which will 
# serve the MathJax.js script. You can easily (in four lines of code) serve
# MathJax.js using http://happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/FileServing.html
# Do not forget the "http://" prefix (e.g. http://localhost:1234/MathJax.js)
```

The link to the tutorial is broken, so I'd be grateful for some assistance. Is there is any MathJax configuration I need to change, or simply extracting the files will do? I'll be writing lots of math in gitit. I'd prefer not to set up Apache etc. to serve MathJax. Gitit already uses Happstack, I'd prefer using that. Thanks!

*EDIT:* Just to be clear I'm not sure how to assign the port 1234 to serve this script

Comment: The link to MathJax's CDN is outdated. Try replacing `d3eoax9i5htok0.cloudfront.net` with `cdn.mathjax.org`. To run MathJax from your own server, see the documentation at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got MathJax working using portable Apache and the MathJax archive downloaded from [docs.mathjax.org](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html). The URL needs to be of the form (assuming you extracted the files into apache2/htdocs/MathJax):

```
http://localhost/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

I wanted to keep this lightweight by reusing the same instance of Happstack as Gitit, but that seems beyond my skills/available time right now.

EDIT: Just found out that ghc will pack everything into one exe when building. So I doubt it is even possible to use the same Happstack instance, as the root directory of the server doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, the `static` directory should work just fine:

> On receiving a request, gitit always looks first in the static
>   directory (or in whatever directory is specified for static-dir in the
>   configuration file). If a file corresponding to the request is found
>   there, it is served immediately. If the file is not found in static,
>   gitit next looks in the static subdirectory of gitit's data file
>   ($CABALDIR/share/gitit-x.y.z/data). This is where default css, images,
>   and javascripts are stored. If the file is not found there either,
>   gitit treats the request as a request for a wiki page or wiki command.
>
> So, you can throw anything you want to be served statically (for
>   example, a robots.txt file or favicon.ico) in the static directory.
>   You can override any of gitit's default css, javascript, or image
>   files by putting a file with the same relative path in static. Note
>   that gitit has a default robots.txt file that excludes all URLs
>   beginning with /_.

(source: https://github.com/jgm/gitit)

Answer (score 0):

Download the `MathJax.js` file from e.g. [cdn.mathjax.org](https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML) and place it in `data/static/js/MathJax.js`. Then change the config you quote to:

```
mathjax-script: http://localhost:5001/js/MathJax.js
```

Comment: But how do I set up localhost:1234 in the first place? Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Sorry didn't see you said port 5001 not 1234

Comment: I tried this but can't get it to work. There is a data/static/js directory structure inside the gitit root directory, I tried to place the files there. But it seems the base URL localhost:5001 actually points to the wiki/wikidata directory. I tried putting files there, but it didn't work either. Perhaps I'm doing this wrong. Also, URL needs to be of the form (in Apache) `http://localhost/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML`