# Displaying mathematical formulas in markdown without external CDN?

Tags: latex, markdown, offline, mathjax, mkdocs

**Background**

We are **merging documentation written in LaTeX and MS Word** towards **markdown** (for the well-known advantages). We have a static intranet site creating **mkdocs**. My predecessors decided for **MathJax**, but this stopped working at the moment [MathJax CDN was shut down](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/), but the customer only realized that with some delay. In the meantime, the intranet is now totally disconnected from the outside world by our customer (whose formulas should stay behind the fence). **Using a different MathJax CDN is therefore no longer an option.**

**The Challenge**

Which options do we have to render the formulas? Rendering LaTeX formulas on the fly using a complete LaTeX installation (similar to http://quicklatex.com/) is not too complicated to set up - except that we do not get the permission to do so.

Can we stick with MathJax? How do we argue that it is simple to run MathJax running without connecting to the CDN? Is there any other solution to render simple mathematical formulas with `mkdocs`?

**Remark**

I used the tag **latex** and **MathJax** on purpose (even though it is not strictly latex- and MathJax-related) since I appreciate your creative ideas on how to render formulas fast, easy and secure.

**Related questions**

- [MkDocs and MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882261/)
- [Local mathjax with mkdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624102/)
- [Updating MathJax CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161254)
- [How do I serve MathJax from a local Happstack server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631307/)

Comment: You might want to start by reading the MathJax documentation on installing MathJax; docs.mathjax.org should get you started.

Comment: Even if not stated explicitly in my question, the documentation is always the first starting point. If everything would have been clear from the documentation, I would not have asked.

Comment: You don't seem to have read https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html (which would be the natural starting point for your question). As it stands, your question is too broad for SO.

Comment: I respectfully disagree about the scope being too wide, and I also edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since many of our clients prefer M$ Word, we decided for the simple and easy-to-argue solution: We keep a Word-document with all formulas in a SharePoint, and we screen-grab them for the use with `mkdocs`.

This solution is not elegant, but it serves the purpose of being secure and easy to maintain. The management decided that a basic `mkdocs`-installation can be expected from the client-IT-service, any additional plugins are considered too much overhead.